# A reliable way of sorting an array and passing that information to a view

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using expressjs to render my routes and pass on database information.

I have two arrays 1. paintingJobs 2. customerList .

The (1) paintingJobs array has a foreign key, which contains the customer ID.

I want to create an array of customers who currently HAVE painting jobs and pass that array onto the view

. To filter the (2)customerList array down to a list of only those customers who currently have painting jobs; I use a series of nested for loops like so.....

```
     for(var i=0; i<paintingJobs.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<customerList.length; j++) {
            if (customerList[j].ID == paintingJobs[i].CustomerID) {
                customerRecords.push(customerList[j]);
            }
        }
     }
```

Creating the new filtered array of customerRecords, which is then passed to the view.

**My Question is:**  If I sort the (1)paintingJobs array by date prior to using it as a filter for my (1)customerList, will the resulting array (customerRecords) be sorted by date as well or more specifically is this a reliable method? If not, would appending the date to the customerList and then sorting the final array be the next best solution?

I am passing this information to my view and then creating an Unordered List based on the number of records.

Thank you for your time and any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your double-loop preserves the order of `paintingJobs` in `customerRecords`, though unless you have duplicate *customerList ID's*, looks somewhat inefficient (why no `break`?).
This means changes to the order of `paintingJobs` before your double loop will be reflected in `customerRecords`. Changes after will not.

```
 paintingJobs.sort(however);

 for(var i=0; i<paintingJobs.length; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<customerList.length; j++) {
        if (customerList[j].ID == paintingJobs[i].CustomerID) {
            customerRecords.push(customerList[j]);
            break; // next paintingJob
        }
    }
 }
```

It looks like the items in `customerList` are *Objects*, so if you make a change to an *Object* in `customerList`, this change will also appear in `customerRecords` even after your double loop.

Comment: That makes sense, I do not understand why I need the break though, would it not go to the top of the inner for loop anyway?

Comment: @Four_lo are you expecting more than one item in `customerList` to have the same `ID`? If yes, don't `break`. If no, then when you've found your customer from `customerList`, why do you need to check the rest of `customerList` for another customer - end that loop and continue to next item in `paintingJob`.

Comment: O i C. I am only expecting one item in customerList to have the give uniqueID. So your solution as it stands will bring be to the next item in the paintJobs array after it finds a match?

Comment: Yes. It also indicates where to sort your _Array_ and why, too.

Comment: Looks like it. Awesome. Your explanation was great, I appreciate the additional knowledge about breaking that loop.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a answer to your original question, but concerning performance i would create something like a test- object with the ID as key,like

```
for(var i=0; i<paintingJobs.length; i++) {
testArray[paintingJobs[i].ID] += 1;
}

for(j=0; j<customerList.length; j++) {
testArray[customerList[j].ID] += 1;
}
```

and check where the testObject has the value 2.
Then with these keys run your operations.
This method will be MUCH faster as your nested loop.

Comment: This will not let you sort before creating the final desired _Array_ and OP indicated that the information on how to sort that _Array_ will not be stored in it. EDIT: Removed my +1 because I just thought, won't every item from `paintingJobs` become `2` or more, so not be helpful?

Comment: I think your idea was something like `obj[customer.id] = customer` _loop_ then sort `paintingJobs` then `records.push(obj[job.ID])` _loop_, but your code didn't match it. (I didn't suggest this because imagine how much memory you'd need for long customer lists)

Comment: Like i said: my snippet is just a hint to NOT NEST Loops like in the questions.